# How to access text of the selected Kendo menu item

Tags: kendo-ui

I need to display the title of my page as the text of the menu item so how can I access the text of the selected menu item?

Comment: Access the kendo ui documentation http://docs.kendoui.com/ to information like this

Comment: The kendo ui documentation has the details about catching the select method, not how to access already selected item.

Comment: Have you looked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107416/how-to-retrieve-id-value-in-kendo-menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `e.item` field of the [select](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/menu#events-select) menu event. Then use the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) jQuery method to get the text. The trick is to avoid getting the text of the child menu items. Here is how

```
$("#menu").kendoMenu({
  select: function(e) {
    var text = $(e.item)
                .clone()
                .find("ul")
                .remove()
                .end()
                .text();

    alert(text);
  }
});
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/amijud/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and best way is to use

```
e.item.firstChild.innerText
```